# What program is there that can unzip files to the usb port?

Tags: helpfile

I would like to find a program for ubuntu  that can unzip files to your usb port, I have been to every website for ubuntu programs that I was able to locate, and could not find any relevance in any thing I came across.

Comment: "to an usb port"?! Or do you mean to a hard disk connected to an usb port? You do know any archiver can be told to extract the file to a destination? That is not enough?

Comment: Which are those websites that couldn't provide an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You only need the standard archive manager. After opening an archive file with the archive manager, you can select the `Extract` button. This will give you the standard file selection window from which you can select your USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:
>

> `unzip <Zipped Archive> && cp */media/<usbdevice>`